# Splitting a row depending of known variable stored in an other database

Tags: mysql, sas, proc-sql

I'm in SAS so the code is not pure MySQL.

I have a table like this

```
ID     Fruits
1      Apple-Water-melon
2      Pine-Apple-Kiwi
```

But also another one with every different fruits

```
ID     Fruits
x      Apple
x      Kiwi
x      Pine-apple
x      Water-melon
```

How can I have a final table like this ?

```
ID    Fruits
1     Apple
1     Water-melon
2     Pine-apple
2     Kiwi
```

Is it possible to parse the first table and splitting the variable if they match one found in the second table ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it `Pine-Apple` or `Pine-apple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FINDW() function to check if the FRUIT value appears in the FRUITS list.

```
data have ;
  input ID Fruits $40.;
cards;
1      Apple-Water-melon
2      Pine-Apple-Kiwi
;

data list;
  fruitid +1 ;
  input fruit $40. ;
cards;
Apple
Kiwi
Pine-apple
Water-melon
;

proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select a.*,b.* 
  from have a 
    left join list b
    on 0 ne findw(Fruits,fruit,'-','ti')
  ;
quit;
```

Results

```
Obs    ID         Fruits          fruitid    fruit

 1      1    Apple-Water-melon       1       Apple
 2      2    Pine-Apple-Kiwi         1       Apple
 3      2    Pine-Apple-Kiwi         2       Kiwi
 4      2    Pine-Apple-Kiwi         3       Pine-apple
 5      1    Apple-Water-melon       4       Water-melon
```

How do you want to eliminate the match for APPLE embedded in the middle of PINE-APPLE?  Do you want give priority to multiple word fruit names first and then eliminate those fruit from the fruit list string?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm ! Could you just explain how 'on 0 ne findw(Fruits,fruit,'-','ti')' is working ? What does mean 'on 0 ne' here ?

Comment: `ON` is the SQL keyword for specifying the condition to use with the join.  Only the combinations that result in true will be output.  `ne` is binary boolean not equal operator. The FINDW() function will return zero when the searched for word is not found.